# Linux + how to verify openssl is up and running

Tags: linux, openssl

As part of installing SCOM application on a Linux machine

Link: http://www.tekronin.net/2014/07/31/monitoring-linux-servers-with-scom-2012-r2/

I need to verify if OpenSSL is up and running.

What is the way do verify this package is on Linux machine?

Comment: OpenSSL doesn't run in the background. I would just check if it is installed, and if the version is up to date (`openssl version`).

Answer (score 5):

Caution, the page seems to mistake SSL with SSH. They both deal with asymmetric cryptography (private-public key pairs) but they are not interchangeable, compatible, and have virtually nothing more in common:

> OpenSSL should be up and running to for certificate signing. This is
>   vital if you have couple of SCOM management servers and wish to use a
>   SSH key for authentication

But it doesn't hurt to check if OpenSSL is available for certificate signing:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout delete_me.pem -out delete_me_cert.pem -days 3653
rm delete_me.pem
rm delete_me_cert.pem
```

These commands should complete without errors and don't require `root` access or `sudo` access. The commands simply test if you can create dummy  keys and sign a dummy certificate and then delete them. The commands don't change anything in the system and don't have any noticeable side effects.

Comment: The protocols SSH and SSL/TLS are different, but the implementation OpenSSH (normally used on LInux) uses OpenSSL's `libcrypto` internally, until recently in all versions and even now in most. In particular it uses OpenSSL's 'PEM' file formats for privatekeys in most cases, meaning you can use or at least maintain those keypairs with OpenSSL. But I don't see how SSL-style (X.509) certs would be useful; they say 'SSH keys for authentication' and for OpenSSH that means `ssh-keygen` not `openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which distribution of Linux you happen to use. In Debian and Ubuntu (which I happen to use), OpenSSL is provided by the `openssl` package, which contains the frontend and depends on the right version of the OpenSSL library. Checking the versions and the status of both the frontend and the library can be done with the following command:

```
dpkg -l 'openssl*'
```

`ii` means "installed". Anything else means you either didn't install OpenSSL or the system failed to install the packages.